call a chatGPT Assistant through API in R
I'm trying to create a GPT in R for my shinyapps using an specific assistant created in the openAi platform
So far I have managed to call the API's (or even use a document as a reference) in R itself, but still don't know how to call an Assistant
This is the code I'm using, but where do I call the assistant?
request("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions") |>
req_auth_bearer_token(token = api_key) |>
req_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json") |>
req_body_json(
data=list(model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
messages=list(
list(role="user",content="2 + 1, where 2 represents a 5 and 1 represents a -1")
))
)|>
req_perform()

Thanks in any help

So what exactly is wrong with this code? Do you get an error of some sort? Is the returned value not what you expect? You seem to be calling the /chat/completions/ endpoint but you say you want to use assistants? That seems to be at a separate endpoint: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants. Maybe check that documentation first.

with this code, nothing. I don't know how to modify it so that I can use an specific assistant, but I think it's not possible to use Assistants created in openAI to be called in API's
